# errors: does not provide an export named when using vite in grpc-web project

Tags: vite, grpc-web

I'm trying to use vite

I've some JavaScript-generated files for GRPC communication; alongside each file, there is a declarative file because I'm using React with TypeScript. When running Vite, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/grpc-web/offboard/dashboard/web_vantage_server/proto/display_option_pb.js' does not provide an export named 'DisplayOption'

Anybody has encountered this issue and has a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please check if the file 'display_option_pb.js' exports the 'DisplayOption' like  export function DisplayOption() { }

Comment: there is a file named display_option_pb.d.ts , and export the class like  ``export namespace DisplayOption {
  export type AsObject = {  "

Comment: same here using ts-protoc-gen, migrating my code to Vite from Webpack, saw a recommendation to use: https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts 
which does work great but needs complete code refactor since the output is _pb.ts file and the previous _pb.js and the _pb.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter the same problem and find this page.

The only solution that I found is mentioned here:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/1242

One needs to use `protobuf-ts` instead of `protoc-gen-grpc-web` protoc plugin. Then you can use Vite with gRPC-web.